# Is going to sleeping with socks beneficial or detrimental?

Tags: sleep, body-temperature, feet, sleep-aids

I've recently read this piece:

[Is sleeping with socks on good for you?](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/321125.php)

from "MedicalNewsToday", and supposedly reviewed by a "PhD, RN". Having moved into a poorly-insulated apartment, and being generally sensitive to cold in my feet I'm considering this possibility. Now that I've heard a pro-socks spiel - I'd like to ask:

- Whether any research has been done on the effect of socks on quality of sleep, particularly in colder ambient temperature and/or with people who report feeling cold feet in bed. (If it's anecdotal / local small sample study - please mention that.)
- Can an opposite case be made - against sleeping with socks - based on established medical fact, even if the conclusion is more speculative (like in the link I gave)?

PS - For the sake of discussion let's ignore the fact there are many kinds of socks one could use.

Answer (score 3):

First, some anecdotal evidence:

Whenever I slept in cold environments (cold room, camping), the feet were usually the first that got cold to the point I was not able to sleep. An obvious solution was wearing socks, which usually helped.

The opposite is also true. When wearing socks makes me too warm, I may not be able to sleep, so I remove them and it helps.

I'm convinced, many people have the exact same experience.

The article linked from the question links to 2 studies about socks and sleep:

**1.** [Skin temperature and sleep-onset latency: changes with age and insomnia (PubMed, 2007)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17070562):

The abstract of this study just says that wearing socks accelerated the sleep onset in adults. They don't even mention any temperatures.

**2.** [Warm feet promote the rapid onset of sleep (Nature, 1999)](https://www.nature.com/articles/43366):

This study does not specifically mention socks but claims that vasodilation in the feet (which can be stimulated by wearing socks, btw) accelerates sleep onset.

> Here we show that the degree of dilation of blood vessels in the skin
>   of the hands and feet, which increases heat loss at these extremities,
>   is the best physiological predictor for the rapid onset of sleep.

More studies about how warm feet can help you fall asleep:

- [Effects of feet warming using bed socks on sleep quality and thermoregulatory responses in a cool environment (PubMed, 2018)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5921564/)
- [Sleep Environment Recommendations for Future Spaceflight Vehicles (NASA, 2016)](https://ston.jsc.nasa.gov/collections/TRS/_techrep/TM-2016-219282.pdf)